# Flutter go router do not navigate after initial route

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-go-router

I am new to GoRouter, using go router I am able to navigate to initial route that is set as path "/". But after that it is not navigating to other paths.

The first page navigates to splash_screen successfully.
After 5 seconds timer, the page should navigate to intro_screen page.
But this navigation do not work, the page will still be on splash_screen.

**Note: the splash_screen.dart and intro_screen.dart are in different folders. I am not sure if we need to these to be in same folders.**

[image]

Below is my code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:example/app_routes/app_route_configuration.dart';
import 'package:example/splashscreen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();


  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget? child;

  MyApp({this.child});

  static void restartApp(BuildContext context){
    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!.restartApp();
  }

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Key key = UniqueKey();
  void restartApp(){
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routeInformationParser: AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routerDelegate,
      routeInformationProvider: AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}
```

**app_route_configuration.dart**

```
import 'package:example/app_routes/app_route_constants.dart';
import 'package:example/authentication/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:example/splashscreen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:example/introscreen/intro_screen.dart';

class AppRouter{

  static GoRouter returnRouter(bool isAuth) {
    GoRouter router = GoRouter(
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              name: AppRouteConstants.splashRouteName,
              path: '/',
              pageBuilder: (context, state){
                return const MaterialPage(child: MySplashScreen());
              },
          ),
          GoRoute(
              name: AppRouteConstants.loginRouteName,
              path: '/login',
              pageBuilder: (context, state){
                return const MaterialPage(child: LoginScreen());
              }
          ),
          GoRoute(
              name: AppRouteConstants.introScreenRouteName,
              path: '/intro_screen',
               pageBuilder: (context, state){
                return const MaterialPage(child: MyIntroductionScreens());
              }
          ),
        ],
      redirect: (context, state) {
          if(!isAuth){
            return context.namedLocation(AppRouteConstants.loginRouteName);
          }
      }
    );
    return router;
  }

}
```

**app_route_contants.dart**

```
class AppRouteConstants {
  static const String splashRouteName = 'splash';
  static const String loginRouteName = 'login';
  static const String introScreenRouteName = 'intro_screen';
}
```

**splash_screen.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../app_routes/app_route_constants.dart';
import '../introscreen/intro_screen.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class MySplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MySplashScreen> createState() => _MySplashScreenState();
}

class _MySplashScreenState extends State<MySplashScreen> {


  startTimer(){
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5),() async{
     GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(AppRouteConstants.introScreenRouteName);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset("images/logo1.png"),
              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
              const Text(
                "Splash Screen",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**intro_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:introduction_screen/introduction_screen.dart';

import '../app_routes/app_route_constants.dart';

class MyIntroductionScreens extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyIntroductionScreens({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: IntroductionScreen(
        pages: [
          PageViewModel(
            title: 'TITLE 1',
            body: 'BODY 1',
            image: buildImage("images/intro_image_1.jpg"),
            decoration: getPageDecoration(),
          ),
          PageViewModel(
            title: 'TITLE 2',
            body: 'BODY 2',
            image: buildImage("images/intro_image_2.jpg"),
            decoration: getPageDecoration(),
          ),
          PageViewModel(
            title: 'TITLE 3',
            body: 'BODY 3',
            image: buildImage("images/intro_images_3.jpg"),
            decoration: getPageDecoration(),
          ),
        ],
        onDone: (){
          context.pushNamed(AppRouteConstants.loginRouteName);
        },
        onSkip: (){
          GoRouter.of(context).pushNamed(AppRouteConstants.loginRouteName);
        },
          //ClampingScrollPhysics prevent the scroll offset from exceeding the bounds of the content.
        scrollPhysics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        showDoneButton: true,
        showNextButton: true,
        showSkipButton: true,
        skip: const Text("Skip", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
          next: const Icon(Icons.forward),
          done: const Text("Done", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
          dotsDecorator: getDotsDecorator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  //widget to add the image on screen
  Widget buildImage(String imagePath) {
    return Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          imagePath,
          width: 450,
          height: 500,
        ));
  }


  //method to customise the page style
  PageDecoration getPageDecoration() {
    return const PageDecoration(
      imagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
      pageColor: Colors.white,
      bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 20, right: 20),
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
      bodyTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15),
    );
  }

  //method to customize the dots style
  DotsDecorator getDotsDecorator() {
    return const DotsDecorator(
      spacing: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
      activeColor: Colors.indigo,
      color: Colors.grey,
      activeSize: Size(12, 5),
      activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
      ),
    );


  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your main like this :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
Key key = UniqueKey();
  void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: AppRouter.returnRouter(true),
      // routeInformationParser:
      //     AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routeInformationParser,
      // routerDelegate: AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routerDelegate,
      // routeInformationProvider:
      //     AppRouter.returnRouter(true).routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why it didn't work with the previous configuration?